# Error in delete a user in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I can't delete a user. This is the error i get when i click the delete button. org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '1']; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). Please help thanks a lot

Jdbc function of delete

```
public int deleteUser(int id){
        String SQL = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '"+id+"'";
        System.out.print(SQL);
        int user = jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
        return user;
    }
```

delete controller

```
RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            SyntacksJdbc syntacksJdbc = (SyntacksJdbc)context.getBean("syntacksJdbc");
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            int user1 = syntacksJdbc.deleteUser(id);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Questions updated successfully.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Error occured in posting question.");
        }

        return new ModelAndView("users");
```

on my jsp button

```
 <a href="/Project/delete?id=${user.id}" name="delete"><button type= submit>Delete</button>
```

Comment: change query to `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?`

Comment: thanks its working. it now deletes the record

Comment: but i have another problem when returning it back to the page. it results a page not found but the user is deleted though

Comment: what you see in URL after it deletes it ? and how is your view resolver is configrued ?

Comment: on the url is delete/id?=1. it returns page not found. it doesnt go back to the page users.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change query to

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?
```

since you are trying to set parameter value

Comment: Hi Jigar Joshi, what can use as parameter from spring security ?